# Get unique rows and their count in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet as below,

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
|abc|123|Yes|
|jkl|123|No |
|abc|123|Yes|
|abc|567|Yes|
```

I want to get the output like,

```
| A | B | C |Count|
-------------------
|abc|123|Yes|  2  |
|jkl|123|No |  1  |
|abc|567|Yes|  1  |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this helps ?

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A1:C,C1:C}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3, count(Col4) where Col1 <> ''group by Col1, Col2, Col3 label count(Col4)''"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use a pivot table on a column where you data has been concatenated:

[image: WA81111 example]

The formula (copied down to suit) in D2 is:

```
="|"&A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"
```

and the pivot table created from selecting D1:D5, Data > Pivot table... and adding `example` to both **Rows** and **Values** with the latter adjusted to Summarise by: COUNTA.